# Compressing a file's name string

Tags: string-manipulation, code-request, files-and-directories, code-review, compression

I was working with files where each name records a lot of information about what is in its respective file and wanted to compress it a little bit. So I wanted to change it's 'base'.

And I noticed that `BaseForm[]` only works with bases from 2 to 36, and besides it does not work with arbitrary representations, like if you base 3 was using only the symbols, "y","t", and "x".

So I wrote a simple program and want to post it here for others to use freely or improve on if they feel like it.

Comment: A very simple encode `encode[number_] := StringJoin @@ Part[alphabet,1 + IntegerDigits[number, Length[alphabet]]]` and to decode `decode[string_] := FromDigits[-1 + Flatten[Position[alphabet, #] & /@ Characters[string]], Length[alphabet]]` . The alphabet is whatever collection of characters you want to use. You can get the `number` argument from an ASCII string like this: `FromDigits[ToCharacterCode["hello!"], 256]` and go from number back to string like this `FromCharacterCode[IntegerDigits[114784820031265, 256]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function to compress a file name (lossy though, but okay for my purposes):

```
fileNameStringCompression[originalFileString_, allowedOrderedCharacters_] := 
 Module[{originalPseudoBaseCharacters, originalPseudoBase, compressedPseudoBase, originalNumber, compressedString},
  (* Identify unique characters in the original string and determine pseudo-bases *)
  originalPseudoBaseCharacters = DeleteDuplicates[Characters[ToLowerCase[originalFileString]]];
  originalPseudoBase = Length[originalPseudoBaseCharacters];
  compressedPseudoBase = Length[allowedOrderedCharacters];
  
  (* Check if compression is possible *)
  If[originalPseudoBase >= compressedPseudoBase, 
   Print["ERROR: Compressed Pseudo-base >= Original Pseudo-base"];
   Return[$Failed];
  ];
  
  (* Function to convert string to number in original pseudo-base *)
  originalNumber = Fold[(#1 originalPseudoBase + Position[originalPseudoBaseCharacters, ToLowerCase[#2]][[1, 1]] - 1) &, 0, Characters[originalFileString]];
  
  (* Function to convert number to string in compressed pseudo-base *)
  compressedString = "";
  While[originalNumber > 0, 
   compressedString = StringJoin[allowedOrderedCharacters[[Mod[originalNumber, compressedPseudoBase] + 1]], compressedString];
   originalNumber = Quotient[originalNumber, compressedPseudoBase];
  ];
  
  compressedString
 ]
```

Where:

```
originalFileName="I have 10 Bananas.nb";
allowedCompressedCharacters =Characters["0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy(_-). "];
fileNameStringCompression[originalFileName, allowedCharacters]
```

gives:

```
1gni6ppca2p1g
```

And the decompression can be done by:

```
fileNameStringDecompression[compressedFileString_, originalOrderedCharacters_, allowedOrderedCharacters_] :=
 Module[{compressedPseudoBase, originalPseudoBase, decompressedNumber, originalString, originalPseudoBaseCharacters, lengthOfOriginal},
  (* Initialize bases *)
  compressedPseudoBase = Length[allowedOrderedCharacters];
  originalPseudoBaseCharacters = originalOrderedCharacters;
  originalPseudoBase = Length[originalPseudoBaseCharacters];
  
  (* Convert compressed string back to number in compressed pseudo-base *)
  decompressedNumber = Fold[(#1 compressedPseudoBase + Position[allowedOrderedCharacters, #2][[1, 1]] - 1) &, 0, Characters[compressedFileString]];
  
  (* Estimate the length of the original string based on the decompressed number *)
  lengthOfOriginal = Ceiling[Log[originalPseudoBase, decompressedNumber + 1]];
  
  (* Convert number back to original string in original pseudo-base *)
  originalString = "";
  While[lengthOfOriginal > 0,
   originalString = StringJoin[originalPseudoBaseCharacters[[Mod[decompressedNumber, originalPseudoBase] + 1]], originalString];
   decompressedNumber = Quotient[decompressedNumber, originalPseudoBase];
   lengthOfOriginal--;
  ];
  
  originalString
 ]
```

Where:

```
allowedCharacters =Characters["0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy(_-). "];
uncompressedCharacters={"i"," ","h","a","v","e","1","0","b","n","s","."};
fileNameStringDecompression["1gni6ppca2p1g",uncompressedCharacters, allowedCharacters]
```

Gives:

```
 have 10 bananas.nb
```

But since in my special personal use case the first value is always a '(', I am not worried about it.